# Send POST request with JSON object and query param to REST webservice using alamofire

Tags: json, swift, post, alamofire

I'm trying to send POST request to REST webservice using alamofire

I'm passing json object as POST body, and i'm getting the response and everything works fine till now

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, path, parameters: createQueryParams(), encoding: .JSON)
            .responseArray { (request, response, myWrapper, error) in
                if let anError = error
                {
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                    println("Error in handling request or response!")
                    return
                }
                completionHandler(myWrapper, nil)
        }

private class func createQueryParams() -> [String:AnyObject]{
        var parameters:[String:AnyObject] = [String:AnyObject]()
        parameters["lat"] = lLat!
        parameters["lng"] = lLon!

        if category != nil { // here is the problem
            parameters["category"] = category!
        }

        return parameters
    }
```

I have a category filter, if there is a value in category variable, i want to send it as QueryParam (should encoding be .URL? but how can i send json object ??)

this code does not work

```
if category != nil {
            parameters["category"] = category!
        }
```

How can i do this? Hope I can explain it clearly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve it this way:

```
let mutableUrlRequest = NSMutableUrlRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path)
mutableUrlRequest.HTTPMethod = .POST
let request = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableUrlRequest, parameters: createQueryParameters()).0

Alamofire.request(request)
```

However, I would advise you to look into the Router declaration of Alamofire and try this one. With it you can create dynamic requests and all of them are declared in a single file.

Edit:
Oh wait you can forget the previous edit the solution is quite simple and you also answered it by yourself. Yes you just have to change the encoding to .URL, you still are able to send json objects, because Alamofire itself decodes then the json object to a string for queryparams.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, path, parameters:createQueryParams(), encoding: .URL).responseArray...
```

Edit 2:
Since the first edit did not work, try this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: path)!
let urlRequest = NSURLReqeust(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "Post"
let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
let request = encoding.encode(urlRequest, createQueryParams())
Alamofire.request(request)
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer, unfortunately this is not supported :(

Comment: which Alamofire version are you using?

Comment: alamofire version 1.2.2

Comment: thank u so much but where should i add these lines ?

Comment: but when i changed the encoding to .URL i couldn't get the response :(

Comment: Ok I added to my previous edit (from the readme) now your code, however since Alamofire 1.2.2 is a bit too old for my version of xcode (and it would take me hours to download the older version). I just can give example code. However this might work

Comment: Thanx a lot I appreciate your help :)